# Updating test website (IIS)

Tags: html, iis

I have a website hosted on IIS to do some testing. However whenever I change the html files in the website directory and referesh the webpage in my browser (chrome), nothing changes. Do I have to force the server to update and see the new changes, or is there something else?

Comment: maybe it's cached locally in your browser (chrome). try hitting ctrl+F5 on your keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried `ctrl+R` to force a full page reload?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that's not server related problem. (Of course you can try to restart server, or system if nothing helps)

Try followings

- Clean your cookies, browsing history.
- Then force refresh the page by hitting **F5 / CTRL+F5 / CTRL+R**.
- Check with another browser

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you don't need to force any IIS reset or anything of that kind. As the other comments and answers already suggested something else is probably going on:

- browser cache
- perhaps IIS is not serving the files you're changing (a duplicate perhaps)
- ... etc

Try some [Rubber Duck Debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to find the problem, helped me out more than once with this kind of "This should just work, why doesn't it?" problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using IIS for over a decade and it is very good about recognizing changes in your content and serving the latest. You don't have to refresh it. Some files like web.config or global.asa are special and when they are changed IIS will automatically restart the site for you.

Mime types like html, txt, gif, and jpeg are assumed by proxies and browsers to be very static and are cached aggressively in those layers (vs asp, jsp, etc).

This [superuser question talks about refreshing in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/220179/cache-refresh-in-chrome) -- apparently its not always simple.

If, however, you want to give IIS a kick the easiest way is with the command line:

```
iisreset
```

I doubt it will fix your problem but it might make you feel better :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be the browser cache (And yes! sometime Chrome is too smart). As you can see people answer here, their solutions can help. However, I would like to point possible problems of each solution and give my favorite solution.

- clean browser history: no one like it, pretty annoy that you have to clean verytime.
- force refresh by f5 or ctrl +f5: sometime this does not work.
- check with another broswer: you can face the same problem when you do another change.

My favorite solution is that if your url is 'http://localhost/page1.html', you can call as 'http://localhost/page1.html?fake=xxxxx'.  The xxxx can be any thing. You can change it anything you want. This solution fakes different urls for brosers but actually it is not different.

Comment: Interesting. What is that kind of tag normally used for?

Comment: anything but I always use just running numbers.